# How to add bulk quantity option in Product ? -- Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to create this type of product (see attached ScreenShot) in Magento 2. If anybody knows please help ..!!

[image]

Comment: This is tier pricing in Magento 2 https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html